# How to prove that $(\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x})^3=\cosh 6x+\sinh 6x$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

How to prove that
$$(\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x})^3=\cosh 6x+\sinh 6x$$
I have tried using the Dmoivres theorme

Comment: De Moivre's is not at all required just use $tanhx=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$

Comment: In the end i got $e^{6x}$=$e^{6x}$ LHS = RHS thanks @EkaveeraKumarSharma.